# Where to find ZK sclass available items?

Tags: css, styles, zk

I'm using ZK and I want to make use of the ZK sclasses for the items in my .zul files. 
I saw that you can use things like :

```
<style>
    div.z-tree {
    background: none !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}
div.z-tree-body {
    background: none !important;
}
tr.z-treerow-seld, tr.z-treerow-over {
    background: #00533f !important;
}
div.z-treecell-cnt {
    color: #5555ff;
}
.test-class div.z-treecell-cnt {
    color: #ff5555 !important;
}
  </style>
```

Where can I find all those styles, like z-tree-body that I can use and all the attributes I can assign to them or how to search for them?

Comment: do you want to override all the css of zk for particular components or do you want to create a whole new theme?

Comment: @chillworld: no, just override some css for the tree component in this case. More specifically, I want to highlight (change background) of some elements (nodes) in tree, based on some boolean value found in the node model. If someone gets an answer, I would appreciate also to know where they read it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

When I need to override some CSS, I always search the specific CSS classes with the browser developer tools.

Because you want to override the CSS of some nodes but not all, try to use sclass to a specific class of your own.

Example :

```
<style>
    .red {
        color:red;
    }
<style/>
<label sclass="@load(empty vm.property?''':'red')" />
```

You don't need to use the zk classes if it's for particularisme cases. For overriding them all, you can beter use the zk classes.